# A* algorithm: is the heuristic h an input?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

We have a formula of `f=g+h` wherein `g` is the *path cost* and `h` is *the distance* left to the goal.

Given that I only want to move my unit in 4 direction (N,S,E,W), my question is:

Can we consider `h` as an input?  Because we will choose what heuristic to use?  Or not because its value is given automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to know, but the heuristic is constant for all nodes and h's value will be the result of the applied heuristic. f(expected total cost) = g(real cost from begin to node) + h(expected cost from node to end).

Comment: I think if you read this [question and its answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-does-a-pathfinding-work?rq=1), you wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: This is well tread ground as others have mentioned, but:
-The heuristic will be dependent on the application
-The path cost would be a derived input, from the inputs current location and goal.

Comment: @AdamS: No, the heuristic function is **not necessarily** constant for all nodes (That is merely a common and simple implementation choice). When executing a **ALT** implementation, the heuristic is the difference of the lengths of the pre-computed path from two (or more) *landmarks*. See here:http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/GW05.pdf or search for "A-star with Triangle Inequality and Landmarks". These algorithms can speed-up A-star by 2-3 orders of magnitude, as with on-line mapping software.

Comment: @AdamS: Check out my Hexgrid Utilities library for a sample implementation: http://hexgridutilities.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6):

Firstly I would suggest looking at some general A* information and A* tutorials, e.g.:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)
https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm

Secondly, the h function needs to be some sort of heuristic guess on the remaining distance, for example the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). The more accurate the heuristic is, the faster A* will find the optimal solution. However take care not to choose a heuristic that overestimates the remaining distance. This is called an inadmissable heuristic, and is not guaranteed to find the optimal solution. More advanced A* users may intentionally choose an inadmissable heuristic for speed purposes or because the resulting path looks nicer, but leave that until you have a basic implementation working. If you're only moving in 4 directions, the Manhattan distance is a good heuristic.