# Heuristic Cost in A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ai, path-finding

I have been learning about the A* path finding algorithm and I can't understand the heuristic cost in this algorithm. What is it and what is its use in the algorithm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does A\* pathfinding work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-does-a-pathfinding-work)

Answer (score 1):

It is merely a “wild guess about the distance left to goal.”

A guess that does not take into account any obstacles in the world.

So you use the shortest line between points.
[image]

It is the brown distance in the example below, used by the algorithm to compute the actual path in cyan.

It is best to underestimate the true distance, otherwise a path may be generated that is not the shortest.

Comment: Not quite a "wild" guess, as it does have some constraints. To work correctly (to be "admissible"), it has to be an *optimistic* guess, one that's guaranteed to not exceed the true distance/cost.

Comment: At the same time, higher resolution of data is better. -1,0,1 for further/same/closer is technically a valid heuristic, but it won't save much time over Dijkstra.