# How will you go about designing A* pathfinding for a pong game?

Tags: c++

I want to design A* path finding in the pong 2d game.
As far as I know I can just simply design an Ai as in

```
if ball.vector.y>player.vector.y
         moveplayeruo()

else 
         moveplayerdown()
```

Is there any possible way to implement A* on a pong game?

Comment: What makes you want to reach for A* here? What downside do you observe with the code you've shown, that you want to improve upon?

Comment: @DMGregory I just wanna know if its possible in this case as I cant find any tutorial on this

Comment: do you have any obstacles that would inhibit movement from any point A to point B? If the answer is "no", then there is no reason to employ a pathfinding algorithm here.

Comment: It's "possible" in the same sense as using a backhoe to crack a walnut is "possible". Nobody would ever do it that way if there's an easier route available: like a nutcracker, or the code you've shown. But if you want to implement A*, you don't need a pong-specific tutorial to do so. A* is just a graph search algorithm. If you can represent your problem as a graph of nodes connected by edges — here, a chain of positions the paddle can occupy, with edges joining adjacent positions — and distinguish a goal node — here, the position with y = ball y — then you can use any A* implementation on it.

Comment: By any chance, are you in a computer science or game programming class, where an assignment is "implement an algorithm like A* in the context of a game/application of your choice"? If so, Pong is probably not a great choice for such an assignment - you'd want to choose something with a state space that's more complicated to navigate, like one with obstacles, finite resources, or other planning challenges. Pong's state space is so simple you can solve for target positions directly, with no graph search required.

Comment: In this case, maybe you should extend the rules of the pong game to include pathfinding. For example, what the player hits is not a ball but a small robot. There is a procedurally generated maze in the middle of the screen. The small robot uses A* to move quickly in the maze. The player on the other side needs to predict which exit it will take come out and react. This is more a question of game mechanics design than the A* algorithm itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use A*, but it's not a good choice.

As shown in this [excellent answer covering how A* works](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23760/33287), A* is an algorithm for finding the shortest paths between nodes in a graph. A general graph is often shown as something like this:

[image: general graph]

However, this is also a equally valid graph:

[image: graph on a single axis]

As such, you *could* apply A* to this, and that would give you the shortest path from the `A` node to the `F` node. But if we know that all of the nodes are constrained to the X axis, we can use a much simpler, faster algorithm. In this case, we can simply look at the X coordinate of the neighbors for the current node & select the one that is closer to our target.

Similarly as you identified in your question, the code:

```
if (ball.vector.y > player.vector.y)
    movePlayerUp();
else if (ball.vector.y < player.vector.y)
    movePlayerDown();
```

Is a perfectly reasonable way to implement pong AI.

There are often many *possible* ways to solve a problem, but not all solutions are equally suited to different versions of the same problem. In this case, I would say that despite being a popular, fast, robust way to solve many types of pathfinding, A* is poorly suited to the pathfinding problem of directing a pong paddle toward the ball because it is unnecessarily complex. It would work, but it is ill suited to this task.