# A* on a pong game model

Tags: c#

I am doing this project a pong game(in c#) where one paddle is a ball reactive AI and other should be A* AI with max 0.05s think time.
I have made a ball tracking reactive AI but I dont know how to go about to make A* for a paddle. Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Strangely, this is the second time a question has been asked here about using A* in this circumstance. It's strange because this is not a problem a developer would use A* to solve. You can predict the location where the ball will cross the paddle's sweep path directly, then dead-reckon to that point — no graph search needed. If you have a school assignment that demands you implement the A* algorithm, you should choose a different game to implement it in, as it does not make sense here. If you just want to implement Pong AI, you should not bother with A*.

Comment: @DMGregory what if this is a must?

Comment: Then you should edit your original question to clarify what makes it a must.

Comment: @Nomi If you're using A* for pong as part of an assignment, I suggest that you clarify that. Homework questions are allowed (though they must still be within the scope of GDSE) and by identifying your question as homework, the community is encouraged to tailor answers that foster learning. We do ask that you make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself & letting us know what you know (or think you know) helps direct the help where it's needed. You can read more about our guidance on homework [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2659/33287).

Comment: @Pikalek but I straight up dont understand the issue. How is one supposed to design A* for a y axis only.

Comment: You're not "supposed to", it's the wrong solution to this problem. But there's fundamentally no difference between a graph that's a line of nodes vs a graph that's a grid of nodes. They're both graphs. You don't need to modify A* in any way to make it work on graphs of different shapes.

Comment: @Nomi Since this question is closed, I've made an attempt [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/203961/33287) on your previously deleted question to try to explain how you *could* use A* for pong paddle AI & why it's not a good fit for the problem.